# Windows 7: No internet connection after installing Ubuntu via Dual-boot

Tags: networking, windows-7, internet

Today I've installed Ubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows 7, like dual-boot. So, it Ubuntu works perfectly for now on - connects to an internet and discovers the network IP.

The huge problem is in Windows 7: it won't connect to the internet at all. I've tried to use a trobleshooter (though I think it's useless), and that's what it told me:

```
"Local Area Connection" doesn't have a valid IP configuration
```

Running `ipconfig /all` in the cmd gives the following: `Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address: 169.254.251.244`

So, there is my full ipconfig output: http://pastebin.com/fD2JjFU2

Now a small update: I experienced this problem using Ethernet connection. I have a router which uses a different subnet, so I tried to connect the PC to the router via LAN. The connection now works perfectly, but the problem still exists.

Comment: By LAN, do you mean WiFi?

Comment: Nope. Connecting to the WiFi router, using Ethernet cable.

Comment: Just posted an answer, before reading your comment. Now, there are several situations where my advice would be pointless, so I may have to revise.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not *extremely* familiar with Windows, but as a general techie I'll give my two cents.

I'll bet your problem is that the card/connection is configured to connect to some weird kind of DHCP server, based on the "Autoconfiguration IP address". After a simple Google search, one of the first results was this:

`https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8acb7cd1-7028-4ffe-86c9-eb43041cf8b3/how-do-i-get-rid-of-second-169254xx-ipv4-address-on-windows-server-2008-sp2-x86?forum=winservergen`

Scrolling down, you see this

"169.254.x.x is the APIPA (Automatic Private IP Addressing) range. This range in Windows is automatically assigned if no DHCP servers responds or is unavailable in the Network."

There is your problem.

Possible solutions:

1. Look in your settings, and check out the DHCP settings. There may be something wrong. I don't really know exactly where that is in the Control Panel, but it should be under Network Settings, since I've been Linux-exclusive for a while.
2. Set a static IP. Normally these are in the 192.168.1.x range. Again, I don't really know how to set it, check in Network Settings.

If these don't work, remember that Google is your friend. And also, welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: Well, it worked if I was connected to my router. But in that case the connection works as expected. I have a ISP installed switch that has 1st and 4th ports available for the internet. The first one uses my router, the 4th is being connected to PC.